# Creating a draggable and scaleable grid in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Unlike the other HTML5 *how to create a grid* questions, I'm wondering how to make one draggable and scalable.

Drawing the grid is pretty simple:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

c.width = width;
c.height = height;

drawGrid(width, height, 40);

function drawGrid(gridWidth, gridHeight, boxSize) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i <= gridWidth; i += boxSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i, gridHeight);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= gridHeight; i += boxSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i);
    ctx.lineTo(gridWidth, i);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba( 210, 210, 210, 1 )";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now to make it draggable, there are many ways of doing it, but I focused on creating the illusion of an infinite moving grid similar to this:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWN8p.png)
(Sorry, don't have enough credits yet)

As the graph moves toward the right, the lines that are hidden from the canvas size are moved back to the beginning, and vice versa. I'm not too sure how to go about moving the grid with the mouse, as well as the scaling. The lines tend to blur when scaled unlike SVGs. 
What's the quickest way of creating a grid to move around infinitely and scale?

**EDIT**:
I took a similar approach to move the grid around using an image pattern to fill the screen.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var itemIsSelected = false;
var clicked = function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
}

draw(width, height);
draggable('#app');

function draw(width, height) {
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  generateBackground();
}

function draggable(item) {
  var isMouseDown = false;
  document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clicked.x = e.pageX;
    clicked.y = e.pageY;
    $(item).css('cursor', 'all-scroll');
    isMouseDown = true;
  };
  document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isMouseDown = false;
    $(item).css('cursor', 'default');
  };
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isMouseDown == true) {
      var mouseX = e.pageX;
      var mouseY = e.pageY;
      generateBackground(mouseX, mouseY, clicked.x, clicked.y);
    }
  };
}

function generateBackground(x, y, initX, initY) {
  distanceX = x - initX;
  distanceY = y - initY;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var bgImage = document.getElementById("bg")
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(bgImage, "repeat");
  ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.translate(Math.sqrt(distanceX), Math.sqrt(distanceY));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2MupHjw.png" id="bg" hidden>
```

This method does not allow me to scroll left or up. It also speeds up the dragging after a distance and does not deal with negative motion well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Pan and Zoom

I dont have much tine so the code will have to do most of the explaining.

The example below pans and zooms using the mouse and mouse wheel.

The object `panZoom` holds the information regarding the zoom (`scale`) and pan position (`x`, `y`)

To pan just use the change in mouse position to change the `panZoom` `x`, `y` position. You dont need to scale the mouse movements as they are not effected by the zoom.

The zoom is via a function `panZoom.scaleAt(x,y,scale)` where `x`, `y` is the mouse position and scaleBy is the amount to scale the scale by. Eg `panZoom.scaleAt(100,100, 2)` will zoom in 2 times at position 100,100 and `panZoom.scaleAt(100,100, 1/2)` will zoom out 2 times at the same position. See `update` function for more details.

To draw in the `panZoom` coordinate system you need to call the function `panZoom.apply` which sets the context transform to match panZoom's settings. The function `drawGrid` is an example. It draws a grid to fit the current pan and zoom.

Note that to restore the normal screen coordinates just call `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` which you will need to do if you want to clear the canvas.

### Snippet update 2021

I have added

- arguments for `drawGrid(gridScreenSize, adaptive)`

  - `gridScreenSize` size of grid in screen pixels (adaptive mode). In world pixels (static mode)
  - `adaptive` if `true` grid scale adapts to world scale. `false` grid size is fixed. When false the constant `gridLimit` sets the max number of lines to render
- `scaleRate` constant that controls the rate of scaling. See comments for more.
- display text to show current scale.
- checkbox to switch between static and adaptive grid size.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(update);
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false, wheel : 0, lastX : 0, lastY : 0, drag : false};
const gridLimit = 64;  // max grid lines for static grid
const gridSize = 128;  // grid size in screen pixels for adaptive and world pixels for static
const scaleRate = 1.02; // Closer to 1 slower rate of change
                        // Less than 1 inverts scaling change and same rule
                        // Closer to 1 slower rate of change
const topLeft = {x: 0, y: 0};  // holds top left of canvas in world coords.


function mouseEvents(e){
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    if(e.type === "wheel"){
        mouse.wheel += -e.deltaY;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
["mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener(name,mouseEvents));
document.addEventListener("wheel",mouseEvents, {passive: false});

const panZoom = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    scale : 1,
    apply() { ctx.setTransform(this.scale, 0, 0, this.scale, this.x, this.y) },
    scaleAt(x, y, sc) {  // x & y are screen coords, not world
        this.scale *= sc;
        this.x = x - (x - this.x) * sc;
        this.y = y - (y - this.y) * sc;
    },
    toWorld(x, y, point = {}) {   // converts from screen coords to world coords
        const inv = 1 / this.scale;
        point.x = (x - this.x) * inv;
        point.y = (y - this.y) * inv;
        return point;
    },
}
function drawGrid(gridScreenSize = 128, adaptive = true){
    var scale, gridScale, size, x, y, limitedGrid = false;
    if (adaptive) {
        scale = 1 / panZoom.scale;
        gridScale = 2 ** (Math.log2(gridScreenSize * scale) | 0);
        size = Math.max(w, h) * scale + gridScale * 2;
        x = ((-panZoom.x * scale - gridScale) / gridScale | 0) * gridScale;
        y = ((-panZoom.y * scale - gridScale) / gridScale | 0) * gridScale;
    } else {
        gridScale = gridScreenSize;
        size = Math.max(w, h) / panZoom.scale + gridScale * 2;
        panZoom.toWorld(0,0, topLeft);
        x = Math.floor(topLeft.x / gridScale) * gridScale;
        y = Math.floor(topLeft.y / gridScale) * gridScale;
        if (size / gridScale > gridLimit) {
            size = gridScale * gridLimit;
            limitedGrid = true;
        }            
    } 
    panZoom.apply();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i += gridScale) {
        ctx.moveTo(x + i, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + i, y + size);
        ctx.moveTo(x, y + i);
        ctx.lineTo(x + size, y + i);
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset the transform so the lineWidth is 1
    ctx.stroke();
    
    info.textContent = "Scale: 1px = " + (1/panZoom.scale).toFixed(4) + " world px ";
    limitedGrid && (info.textContent += " Static grid limit " + (gridLimit * gridLimit) + " cells");    
}   
function drawPoint(x, y) {
    const worldCoord = panZoom.toWorld(x, y);
    panZoom.apply();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();   
    ctx.moveTo(worldCoord.x - 10, worldCoord.y);
    ctx.lineTo(worldCoord.x + 10, worldCoord.y);
    ctx.moveTo(worldCoord.x, worldCoord.y - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(worldCoord.x, worldCoord.y + 10); 
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); //reset the transform so the lineWidth is 1
    ctx.stroke();  
}

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
function update(){
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
        w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
        h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
    if (mouse.wheel !== 0) {
        let scale = 1;
        scale = mouse.wheel < 0 ? 1 / scaleRate : scaleRate;
        mouse.wheel *= 0.8;
        if(Math.abs(mouse.wheel) < 1){
            mouse.wheel = 0;
        }
        panZoom.scaleAt(mouse.x, mouse.y, scale); //scale is the change in scale
    }
    if (mouse.button) {
       if (!mouse.drag) {
          mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
          mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
          mouse.drag = true;
       } else {
          panZoom.x += mouse.x - mouse.lastX;
          panZoom.y += mouse.y - mouse.lastY;
          mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
          mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
       }
    } else if (mouse.drag) {
        mouse.drag = false;
    }
    drawGrid(gridSize, adaptiveGridCb.checked);
    drawPoint(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
div { 
  position : absolute; 
  top : 5px; 
  left : 5px; 
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #FFFD;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>
<label for="adaptiveGridCb">Adaptive grid</label>
<input id="adaptiveGridCb" type="checkbox" checked/>
<span id="info"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than I wanted! I was going to try to make the extra lines appear on my own.

Comment: If I needed to, how do I prevent the subdivision of the grid when zoomed in, so only the same grid lines are there the whole time, getting larger when zoomed in or smaller when zoomed out?

Comment: @TomJaquo Change the second line in the function `drawGrid` to `var gridScale = 128;` The 128 is in pixels and can be any value. Warning the code will try to draw all visible grid lines, which can quickly mount up to a lot of lines when zooming out.

Comment: One more follow-up I can't figure out. How do I set a max and min scroll distance for the grid? Adding a size limit on the `drawGrid` function just stops drawing the graph instead of freezing the max or min scale of the graph.

Comment: To limit the scale add `scale = panZoom.scale * scale < minScale ? minScale / panZoom.scale : scale`; and `scale = panZoom.scale * scale > maxScale ? maxScale / panZoom.scale : scale;`  above the line `  panZoom.scaleAt(mouse.x,...` in the `update` function. Define `minScale` and `maxScale` to the limits you want. `minScale` the smaller value represents zooming in and `maxScale` the larger value represents zooming out.

Comment: @Blindman67 how to make horizontal and vertical scrolling limited (grid has a size)? like you suggested for `minScale` and `maxScale`. So is it going to be like, `min/maxWidth` and `min/maxHeight`