# How can I get the mouse's position on a movable canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

**modified with the solution I found**
*Simply multiplying the e.clientX/clientY by 2 did the trick!*

I am trying to create an art app with HTML and a js canvas. I need to get the mouse's position on the canvas. But I need to take into account the canvas's size, position, scale, rotation, and zoom. I am using the [panzoom library](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom#faq) for my zooming. My current code looks like this, but it is still offset problematically:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // Canvas.
const canvasArea = document.getElementById("canvasarea"); // Canvas parent.

ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finish);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", finish);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
    // If the player left clicks we start moving, else we ignore.
    if (evt.button === 0) {
        drawing();
    }
});

// Make the canvas the same size as its parent.
function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.setAttribute("width", canvasArea.clientWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", canvasArea.clientHeight);
}

// Run this right away.
resizeCanvas();

function draw(e){
    if (!paint) return 0;
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    let x = ((e.clientX*2 - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width);
    let y = ((e.clientY*2 - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height);
```

The canvas' width and height attributes are equal to its clientWidth and clientHeight.

HTML:

```
<div class="canvasarea center" id="canvasarea" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; zoom: 0.5;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to multiply the canvas pixel coords `e.clientX`, `e.clientY`. by the inverse transform.  panZoom  does not provide that functionality.  The answer Pan and Zoom https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329817/3877726 has all you need to zoom/pan the canvas 2D API (I have just added `toWorld` to convert pixel coords to world (panned zoomed) coords). It does not apply zoom to CSS, it does not change the pixel size

Comment: How can I get the inverse transform?

Comment: To complicated to answer as a comment. See link in previous comment, or search SO for inverse transform