# How to add small square shaped grid to DIV element using the HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a `div` element within my application. I want to add background to it. The background should consist of small squares. As I would like to draw some shapes on top of it. I am unable to follow what exactly needs to be done in order to get these grids in the background. Can someone please help?

I want the whole `div` portion within the `HTML page` to look something like this:

It should Something like this:
[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <v-stage ref="stage" class="stage">
          <v-layer ref="layer"> </v-layer>
        </v-stage>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {};
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  .stage {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Because you mentioned wanting to draw on top of this grid, I'd recommend using a `<canvas>` element, and then in JS you can paint the background grid on the canvas. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310138/creating-a-draggable-and-scaleable-grid-in-html5 as an example.

Comment: You can make an image of that and set it as the background image. Did you try that?

Comment: you want this: https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/RwVOYZY ?

Comment: Unless you need it to be responsive, or dynamic, or you need it to be somehow interactive or accessible for the user, this seems like a good case for a small, repeated background image...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please provide this as an answer so I can mark it as an answer. I used your approach and worked out for me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A background can do it:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: 
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px),#366 270deg, #0000 0),
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 1px),#a9a9a9 270deg, #0000 0);
  background-size: 100px 100px, 20px 20px; /* adjust the size like you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing this to my `KonvaJS Stage` and the following is the complete code sample in incase it it's required for someone in the future:

```css
<style scoped>
.root {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --line-color-1: #D5D8DC;
  --line-color-2: #a9a9a9;
}

.body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.stage {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-image:
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px),var(--line-color-1) 270deg, #0000 0),
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 1px),var(--line-color-2) 270deg, #0000 0);
  background-size: 100px 100px, 20px 20px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="root" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="stage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```